# How to RDP connect interactively to a Windows machine from a non Windows RDP client?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm relying on a third party application (http://pgina.org) to achieve an interactive RDP login to a Windows 11 workstation for users accredited from an external user database.

Following this [official Microsoft recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-connection-6-prompts-credentials), I appended this line at the end of the RDP file (saved from Windows RDP client): enablecredsspsupport:i:0

so that the RDP client does not require user/credential but instead redirects to the interactive log screen. This works fine from Windows RDP clients but it does not work from  from other OS (official Microsoft RDP clients).

Is there a workaround that would work for all OS?

Comment: It might help to install xrdp but I am not sure about that.  I have xrdp install to get into a linux machine.

Comment: Connect to the console or admin session instead. Usually adding /admin to the ip:port is enough, but some clients have a switch you need to use to do it. For mstsc.exe, you can either do mstsc /admin or just run mstsc and then in the ip field enter `12.34.56.78:3389 /admin`

Comment: Which Non-Windows RDP client do you use that supports `.rdp` files?

Comment: On macOs: https://apps.apple.com/es/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id1295203466?mt=12

Comment: On android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.androidx

Comment: Any further thoughts on this problem? Why is this feature supported by the native Windows RDP client but not the official Microsoft RDP client of other OS?